# How to enable multiuser support in AVD 4.2

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-virtual-device

Is there any way how to enable multiuser support in the new (emulator) AVD with Android 4.2 (ADT version 21)? On real device there should be User menu item in Settings, but on my AVD is missing. I know that this feature is enabled only for certain tablet devices but I didn't find any kind of setting when creating AVD or editing device in the new Device Definitions section. Even creating device from Nexus 7 profile with Android 4.2 didn't help.
Any suggestions how to enable this feature? Thanks!

Comment: I asked this question in ADOH here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PaH7EC6FYfk. Time 32:00. They were not sure about the answer and advice was to create "large" AVD or find some option when creating device. So I'm at the same place as I was.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For me this works on a 10.1 Jelly Bean avd:

1. adb shell
2. su
3. setprop fw.max_users 5

From here: http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?p=34350909

Comment: Thanks! This works. Just for the record - You don't need to have "big screen"/tablet device to enable this feature, but you don't see users on lock screen.

Comment: @Warlock: i have tried it out but getting "setprop: command not found" this is beacause dnt know the path in which i have to go and run it. could you help me?

Comment: Does this hack still works in latest android emulator . Tried for 4.3 AVD, it didn't work.

Comment: When I select Add user, the emulator getting **restart**. Anything more I need to do..??