# multi-user feature of JellyBean in Emulator From Ubuntu

Tags: android, eclipse, sdk, emulation, android-4.2-jelly-bean

I know multi-user functionality is available in Android 4.2 JellyBean:

I have **`My Nexus 7 Emulator with Jellybean 4.2`**

I am using Ubuntu 11.10.

I have gone through [here](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/jelly-bean.html#42-multiuser) and [here](https://www.android.com/whatsnew/).

But I want to test this feature on my emulator and not on the actual device.

**My Questions:**

1. Is it possible to test multi-user feature on an emulator?
2. If yes, how it can be?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Create an AVD with device = `Nexus 7`.  Start the AVD, and then follow the instructions given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13376607/how-to-enable-multiuser-support-in-avd-4-2).

Comment: @iafreen: Thnks for your valuable support. i have refered your given link. but the Solution accepted is not getting perfectly by me. have your tested the same for your emulator?

Comment: Yes, I have tested it.  It works for me at least as far as adding a new user and switching to them.  Where are you running into trouble?  The sequence I use is -- launch AVD (must be tablet size, I use the `Nexus 7` profile).  After the tablet boots, then do the adb commands listed, then go to `Settings`, there should be a new option under device called "Users" where you can add users.

Comment: Ok thanks for your quick reply. i have tried it out but getting "setprop: command not found" this is beacause dnt know the path in which i have to go and run it. could you help me?

Comment: interesting. On my AVD, it was in my path once I got a shell and su'd to root.  It is located at `/system/bin/setprop` on my AVD.

Comment: I also noticed the "su" command is extraneous on my AVD, I get a root shell on the device when I do "adb shell".

Comment: i am guessing you are using windows. and i am using ubantu 11.10. D'nt know but not able to solve my problem until now. bdw thanks for your valuable support.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/21430/discussion-between-iagreen-and-bhavesh)