# Android 7.1.1 multi-user support in emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-7.1-nougat, android-multiple-users

I tried to get the multi-user support for my Android 7.1.1 AOSP **emulator** build on Ubuntu 16.04 64bit. The build gets run with `lunch aosp_x86-eng` and following the emulator with `emulator64-x86`.

I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13376607/how-to-enable-multiuser-support-in-avd-4-2) solution but with no success:

```
adb shell
su
setprop fw.max_users 5
```

The Icon is visible for the first time when I wipe down the status bar, but disappears on releasing it:

[image: screenshot emulator]

Same like [here](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/105539/multi-user-option-not-avilable-in-android-one-after-lollipop-update):

```
adb shell setprop fw.show_multiuserui 1  
adb shell setprop fw.max_users 4
```

I also tried to [add an user by adb](https://theunlockr.com/2012/08/02/how-to-enable-multiple-users-on-your-jelly-bean-device/) but without success.
After executing the commands I test it by using:

```
su
pm get-max-users
```

result is:

```
Maximum supported users: 4
```

Is there a barrier or something like that? Or do I need to edit the build? If I need to root the system, why is the property set to 4 users? And why is the icon shown on the first wipe and disappears after releasing?

Thanks!